# Does Linux kernel 4.19 work well on Dell Latitude 5491 with Xubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and BIOS version 1.5.1?

Tags: kernel, xubuntu

Does Linux kernel 4.19 work well on Dell Latitude 5491 with Xubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and currently latest BIOS version 1.5.1 (which has delivered great improvement for thermal and fan management by the way)?

Google does not bring up posts with problems here, but maybe anybody can confirm that exactly this combination has worked (I consider to upgrade from 4.15 kernel to 4.19)

Comment: Have you tried it? Or have any reason to think it won't work?

Comment: Your question sounds a little bit picky to me. Recently, there was some backport error in the Xubuntu kernel 4.15, it was improved already next day, but I had to reinstall the system. Due to high work load, I thought better is to find out whether somebody was already successful with exactly the same combination.

Comment: Not I have not tried and can't risk it. Because yes, I have a reason as I have recently had to reinstall the system due to a backport error in the upstream LTS 4.15. kernel.

Comment: Reinstalling should not be necessary, just [booting an older kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version) should be [very easy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739002/reverting-to-previous-kernel-to-avoid-booting-the-new-one-that-breaks-my-system), like "hold shift when booting" easy.

Comment: booting the old kernel did not help unfortunately, it was some problem related to handling of encryprted LVM. Anyway next day there was a new update including new kernel. (= system update was broken as combination of libraries and kernel)

Comment: You want to know if the software will run on the hardware - without installing it? So, why not boot from a CB or USB stick and run it without installing? Won't that tell you what you want to know?

Comment: No. I want to know whether smb was successful doing same.

Comment: How is SMB related, they're just packages aren't they? And they can be installed when running a live ISO. But if booting the old kernel didn't help, then it sounds like the new kernel wasn't the actual problem... It also sounds like you've given yourself no options other than actually booting the new kernel, while simultaneously ruling out that only possible answer.

Comment: @Xen2050 - sorry for using the abbreviation "smb", it's not SMB but "somebody".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was courageous and installed kernel 4.19 and despite some very unpleasant seconds of black screen during boot, it works on the first glance!

I used the following instructions to upgrade the kernel:
https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/

Though, apt-get upgrade prints warnings about the open source nvidia driver.

**UPDATE**

There have been strange freezes on unlocking the screen, so I have downgraded the kernel back to the Ubuntu LTS shipped 4.15.